# is there any way to run 'Background' again?

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io-v4

Background: Login to Control Panel
Given I Load Test Data in "am" for "invalidPostalCodeDetails"
.....
....

```
Scenario Outline: Verify Error Massage For Invalid PostalCode
    Then I expect that the element "Edit Contact Info" is displayed
    ..........

    Examples:
        | country | state   | zip        | message |
        | IN      | KA      | 100        | Error Message |
        | IN      | KA      | 586112     | Success Message |
```

here I want to run background again to login with another user as Scenario Outline: is depended on it.